# Amazon AppFlow vs Amazon EventBridge for event-driven interactions

Tags: amazon-web-services

Amazon EventBridge enables developers to connect 3rd party event-driven applications with Amazon services. Amazon AppFlow offers event-driven integration with 3rd party apps as well.

What is the difference between the two services for the event-driven scenarios and when to use one over the other?

Answer (score 7):

The [AppFlow FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/appflow/faqs/) contains this info:

> Amazon EventBridge enables developers to build event driven
>   applications that interact with SaaS applications and AWS services.
>   SaaS applications that have integrated with EventBridge emit events to
>   the customer’s event bus, which can then be routed to targets such as
>   Amazon EC2 instances or Lambda functions for processing. AppFlow
>   supports bi-directional transfer of data between SaaS applications and
>   AWS services that may be initiated by humans using a UI, a schedule,
>   or events - all with a point and click interface.

AppFlow is great for anyone who wants to connect together their applications without writing any code. EventBridge works with Step Functions and Lambda (and various other AWS services), and so is well suited for developers who need the extra flexibility that those services provide. Right now EventBridge is only one way, whereas AppFlow allows you to send data back to SaaS apps. The list of supported partners for each service is also different.

For some of AppFlow's partners, data is received via API polling (from the FAQ: "AppFlow is a fully managed API integration service that replaces custom connectors"), which is slightly different from EventBridge which receives data in an event-driven manner, where an event is sent via an HTTP call from the partner as soon as a change occurs. The pricing of the two services also differs: EventBridge [charges $1/million events](https://aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/pricing/), and [AppFlow charges $0.001 per flow](https://aws.amazon.com/appflow/pricing/) (with an additional charge per GB of data processed).